# C++ generic insertion sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, generics

I am creating this to try get a better understanding of sorting algorithms and generic functions. I have implemented a basic insertion sort algorithm and I am trying to make it work with multiple data structures (lists and arrays at least).

Since I can access lists like this : list[N] to get the value, I think I need to be using iterators. So I am trying to convert my solution. Here is the basic insertion sort algorithm I am trying to modify:

```
int *insertionsort(int *a)
{
  for (int i = 1; i<length(a); ++i)
  {
    int k = a[i];
    int j = i-1;
    {
      while (j>=0 && a[j] > k)
      { 
        a[j+1] = a[j--];
      }
    a[j+1] = k;
  }
  return a;
}
```

And here is what I have so far for the generic version:

```
template <class T>
T insertionsort(T a)
{
  for (auto i = a.begin()+1; i<a.end(); ++i)
  {
    auto k = i;
    auto j = i-1;
    while (j>=a.begin() && *j>*k)  
    {
      (j + 1) = j--; 
    }
    (j + 1) = k;
  }  
   return a;
}
```

Unfortunatley I can't seem to get this generic function to sort correctly at all. I have been looking at this quite a while with no luck. Ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What's up with the `strlen(a)`? That's not at all how you're supposed to get the length of an array of ints; you have to pass the length around with the array.

Comment: `(j + 1) = anything` doesn't make sense. Did you mean to dereference the iterator?

Comment: On the following page you will find a good example how to implement _insertion sort_ in C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate

Comment: `length(a)` makes no sense either. Also, you have multiple points where you invoke undefined behavior by using `j` and `j--` without a proper sequenced-before relationship. This code is just full of errors.

Comment: This would be a lot more C++ if you conformed to the [algorithms interface](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).

Comment: I was just uses a hard coded length for the string before I posted this. Sorry for the confusion. Could you expand on the undefined behaviour?

Comment: `j>=a.begin()` doesn't make sense. Decrementing the iterator returned by `begin()` is UB for the StdLib containers, so you'll never have a safe iterator that points before `a.begin()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Posted only for the OP's reference, and not likely to live a long life. If you're so inclined to use C++11 and don't like typing, this may do the trick.

```
template<typename Iter>
void insertion_sort(Iter first, Iter last)
{
    for (Iter it = first; it != last; ++it)
        std::rotate(std::upper_bound(first, it, *it), it, std::next(it));
}
```

Relavent links for the functions used:

[`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound), [`std::next`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next), and [`std::rotate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate). Enjoy.

Comment: When I have seen that in @nosid's comment I thought *"WTF, insertion sort in two lines!"*

Comment: +1 for using a binary search to scan the already-sorted subsequence.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are confused with dereferencing iterators/pointers. This should work:

```
template <class T>
T insertionsort(T a)
{
    if(a.begin() == a.end()) // return a when it's empty
        return a;
    for(auto i = a.begin() + 1; i < a.end(); ++i)
    {
        auto k = *i; // k is the value pointed by i
        auto j = i - 1;
        while(j >= a.begin() && *j > k)  
        {
            *(j + 1) = *j; // writen in 2 lines for clarity
            j--;
        }
        *(j + 1) = k;
    }  
    return a;
}
```

Comment: I think it's UB to move `j` past the left end of `a`. If `a` is empty, `a.begin()+1` is also UB.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had a similar solution to this at one point but didn't dereference i when assigning it to auto k. This solution works great.

Comment: @user2357112 You're right. I just simply fixed dereferencing here.

Comment: if A.begin()+1 is UB how would be the best way to access the 2nd element of the input?

Comment: @UserAce if `a.size() == 0` then it is already sorted, so you can simply return it. Using `a.begin() + 1` won't be a problem anymore.

Comment: @pkacprzak I realize that, that is why I want to start on the 2nd element.

Comment: @UserAce I made a fix that returns `a` if `a` is empty, check the code again.

Answer (score 3):

Its better, for a more generic solution, to pass the **range to be sorted** instead of the thing to be sorted, as standard algorithms like [`std::sort()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) do:

```
template <typename BIDIRECTIONAL_ITERATOR>
void insertionsort(BIDIRECTIONAL_ITERATOR begin , BIDIRECTIONAL_ITERATOR end) //Note that the iterators
{                                                                             //are passed by value
    if( begin == end ) return; //If the range is empty, abort

    for(auto i = begin + 1; i < end; ++i)
    {
        auto j = i - 1;
        bool flag = false; //Used to abort the loop after j == begin case
        while(!flag && (j != begin || (flag = j == begin)) && *j > *i)  
        {
          *(j + 1) = *j;
          j -= !flag; //If j == begin, don't decrement (Without branch)
        }
        *(j + 1) = *i;
    }  
}
```

The function is a procedure, does not return anything, sorts the original range.

Comment: I think you can reduce that to a bidirectional iterator by using `std::next` (C++11) instead of `+1`, `i != end` and `j != begin` (though I guess there need to be a special check as `begin-1` might be UB for some cases).

Comment: @WhozCraig I was fixing that now :) Thanks

Comment: Is there more advantages to passing in a range of data then allowing for a subset of the data to be sorted?

Comment: @DyP I was thinking about a bidiractional solution before I posted this, but as you I had noticed that the `j >= begin` equivalent could be a problem. With a bidirectional iterator I'm only allowed to know if two iterators are the same or not, but what we need here is to know if the iterator passed `begin` (Is before `begin`)

Comment: @UserAce yes. The algorithm is more general: You don't disallow the user to sort a specific part of a thing (A container, for example) instead of force to sort the entire thing only.

Comment: @Manu343726 Yes, but this comparison isn't safe. If `j` is ever decremented before `begin`, this decrement might already invoke UB, e.g. if the passed `begin` is the `c.begin()` iterator from a StdLib container. You'd have to check `j > begin()` anyway, therefore you could use `j != begin()` as well.

Comment: @DyP one possible solution, and to avoid the UB-prone comparison, is to set-up a flag when `j == begin` after the `while` loop body execution to stop the loop.

Comment: I suspect the `*(j + 1) = *i;` is now not correct any more (e.g. if  `*i` should be rotated to `*begin`). It might also be simpler to just use the `j != a.begin() && *j > k` comparison in the loop and do a `if(*j > k) { *(j+1) = *j; *j = *i; } else { *(j+1) = *i); }` after the loop.